# Rabbitmq 3.7.6 logging to file not working with docker create command

Tags: docker, logging, rabbitmq

i want rabbitmq logs in separate directory. so i made changes in rabbitmq.conf file:
log.file = /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.log

while creating docker specific environment variable: RABBITMQ_LOGS=rabbitmq.log
(i also want to mount /var/log/rabbitmq to specific folder )

docker create --name rabbitmq   -p 5671:5671  -e RABBITMQ_LOGS=rabbitmq.log -v /xyz/logs/rabbitmqlogs:/var/log/rabbitmq --restart=always   --health-cmd='rabbitmqctl status'   --health-interval=3s --network network rabbitmq-image

But i am getting error below error:

## BOOT FAILED

Error description:
    init:do_boot/3
    init:start_em/1
    rabbit:start_it/1 line 446
    rabbit:'-boot/0-fun-0-'/0 line 294
    rabbit:start_logger/0 line 924
    rabbit_lager:ensure_log_working/0 line 115
    rabbit_lager:'-ensure_log_working/0-lc$^0/1-0-'/1 line 115
    rabbit_lager:ensure_logfile_exist/1 line 158
throw:{error,{cannot_log_to_file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.log",enoent}}
{"init terminating in do_boot",{error,{cannot_log_to_file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.log",enoent}}}
init terminating in do_boot ({error,{cannot_log_to_file,/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.log,enoent}})

Above same i tried with docker run and it is working fine.. but i want it to work with docker create

docker run -it --name rabbitmq -p 5671:5671 -v /xyz/logs/rabbitmqlogs:/var/log/rabbitmq  --restart=always --health-cmd='rabbitmqctl status' --health-interval=3s --network network -e RABBITMQ_LOGS=/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.log rabbitmq

how to resolve above error?

Comment: i am facing this issue while mounting /var/log/rabbitmq to /xyz-locations

Comment: for both the cases docker run and docker create